# Allow VS throw third party libraries exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I'm getting this message silently on output window:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in
>   AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll

How do I allow VS to raise that exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure VS to break even when the exception is handled in user code. Typically the exceptions dialog can be open with `CTRL-ALT-E`, but you can find it in the Debug-> Windows menu for VS2015, or directly in the Debug menu for older versions.

Anyway, once you open it, find the `System.ArgumentException` exception and select `break when thrown`. You also have some additional options in the context menu:

[image]

More on this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/).

Answer (score 2):

You should enable "break when thrown" for exceptions that you are interested in (or you can even enable for all CLR exceptions, but you'll get a lot of noise)
Which version of visual studio you are using?
For VS 2015 go to `Debug->Windows->Breakpoints` and enable checkbox for exceptions you're interested in:
[image: VS2015]

For VS 2013: go to `Debug->Exceptions` and do the same:
[image]